# Unable to understand how changes made in one state variable effects other state variable in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

There's a store kind of implementation where I have a state with many properties. But currently I'm interested in two properties `calculationResults` and `calculatedResults`.

```
import {useState} from 'react';

interface ICalculationResult{
// we have many properties in the interface
}

interface INewExportRequestStoreState {
state: {
calculationResults?: ICalculationResult;
calculatedResults?: ICalculationResult;
}
}

interface INewExportRequestStoreActions {
 actions: {
  createRequest();
  addUserInputUsContent();
  addUserInputUsContentForCalculated();
  }
 }

const createRequest = () =>{
// other logic goes here
var data;
setCalculationResults(data);
setCalculatedResults(data);
}

const addUserInputUsContent = ()=>{
//Makes a call to the Api and retrieves the data. 
}

const addUserInputUsContentForCalculated = () =>{
//Makes a call to the Api and retrieves the data.
}

 const [calculationResults, setCalculationResults]= useState();
 const [calculatedResults, setCalculatedResults] = useState();

const useNewExportRequestStore = (): INewExportRequestStoreState &
INewExportRequestStoreActions  => {
// we have different methods here which will set the state.calculationResults and 
state.calculatedResults
return{
  state:{
    calculationResults,
    calculatedResults
  },
  actions :{
    createRequest,
    addUserInputUsContent,
    addUserInputUsContentForCalculated
  }
}
}

export default useNewExportRequestStore;
```

The state is utilized in the NewCalculation.tsx and passed on to it's child component NewCalculationResults.tsx

Th NewCalculationResults has a dialog box with a button to save the data. When Save is clicked then action method on the store is called passing in the `calculationResults` and `CalculatedResults`.

In Short, `State` is used by `NewCalculation` => `NewCalculationResults` => `addUserInputUsContent` does the modification

```
const addUserInputUsContent = () =>{
 // getting the agreements
var calAgreements = calculationResults.hw.agreements;    
var indices: any = [];
// filtering the calAgreements to extract the desired product
calculatedAgreements = calAgreements.filter((a:any) => a.boQItem.id. == productNo);
// The desired product can be present at multiple indexes. Hence looping through the 
//calagreements to get the all the indexes.
calAgreements.forEach(function(value:any,pos: number){
  if(value.boQItem.id == productNo)
  {
    indices.push(pos);
  }
});
 // Removing the desired product from the calagreements
for(var index = indices.length-1;index>=0;index--)
  {
    calAgreements.splice(indices[index],1);
  } 
// Making an api call passing the desired product array

post<ICalculationResult>(
  `AssessmentRequest/${id}/adduserconinput`,
  {
    productNo,
    calculatedAgreements
   },
   (data: ICalculationResult) => {   
    // Merging the received data on to the existing agreements     
    calculationResults.hw.agreements.push(...data.hw.agreements);
    setCalculationResults(calculationResults);
    });
 }
```

The state action method `addUserInputUsContentForCalculated` is also similar except that it uses `calculatedResults`. But when the method executes, I see the desired product is no more present in the `calculatedResults`. And hence the Api call doesn't pass any data. May be splicing the `calAgreements` in the `addUserInputUsContent` has some effect on `calculatedResults.hw.agreements`.

[Sample code at plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/C4o1fadHHkszSLHC?open=Hello.js&deferRun=1)

Comment: You are modifying the state instead of creating a copy it always will cause errors like this. Any `push` or `splice` that affect state will cause bugs

Comment: When the state is passed down the components as params, don't we get a copy of the state?

Comment: No, it's the same object